# OracleDB 11gのinstall中に出てくるダイアログが小さくて触れない

Tags: centos, oracle

Host: Windows10 Pro 64bit & Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.16
Guest: CentOS 7.5.1804 x86_64
Database: Oracle Database 11gR2

---

CentOS上に11gをinstallしたんですが、途中で出てくるダイアログのサイズが極小で、サイズ変更も許可されておらず、何が書いてあるかわかりません...
右クリックメニューから`Close`させると、install自体は完了できましたが、気持ち悪いですね...

[image: OracleDB install NG]

どうしたら、内容が分かるサイズでダイアログが開かれるんでしょうか？
この現象の原因、回避方法をご教示いただきたいです。

解答よろしくお願いします。